# Functions not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a website i'm doing i have this dropdown array

**Bare Dropdown**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.sansserif {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()" text="white">


<p class="sansserif"> Select Your Phone Brand</p>
<select id="brand" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">
  <option value="1">Apple
  <option value="2">Samsung
  <option value="3">LG
  <option value="4">Other
</select>

<div id="apple">
<p class="sansserif">Select Your Phone Model</p>
  <select id="model1" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">
  <option value="1">iPhone Xs Max
  <option value="2">iPhone Xs
  <option value="3">iPhone X
  <option value="4">iPhone 8+
  <option value="5">iPhone 8
  <option value="6">iPhone 7+
  <option value="7">iPhone 7
  <option value="8">iPhone 6s+
  <option value="9">iPhone 6s
  <option value="10">iPhone 6+
  <option value="11">iPhone 6
  <option value="12">iPhone 5SE
  <option value="13">iPhone 5S
  <option value="14">iPhone 5C
  <option value="15">iPhone 5
  <option value="16">Other
</select>
</div>
<div id="samsung">
<p class="sansserif">Select Your Phone Model</p>
  <select id="model2" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">
  <option value="1">Galaxy S9+
  <option value="2">Galaxy S9
  <option value="3">Galaxy S8+
  <option value="4">Galaxy S8
  <option value="5">Galaxy S7 Edge
  <option value="6">Galaxy S7
  <option value="7">Galaxy S6 Edge+
  <option value="8">Galaxy S6 Edge
  <option value="9">Galaxy S6
  <option value="10">Note 9
  <option value="11">Note 8
  <option value="12">Note 7
  <option value="13">Note 5
  <option value="14">Other
</select>
</div>
<div id="lg">
<p class="sansserif">Select Your Phone Model</p>
  <select id="model" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">
  <option value="1">LG G7
  <option value="2">LG G6
  <option value="3">LG G5
  <option value="4">LG Stylo 4+
  <option value="5">LG Stylo 4
  <option value="6">LG Stylo 3
  <option value="7">LG Stylo 2
  <option value="8">Other
</select>
</div>


<p class="sansserif" id="product"></p>

<div id=iphone-xs-max>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-xs>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-x>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-8+>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-8>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-7+>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $110
<br>CHARGE PORT: $60
<br>SPEAKER: $45
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $55
<br>REAR CAMERA: $115

</div>
<div id=iphone-7>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $105
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>REAR CAMERA: $55

</div>

<div id=iphone-6s+>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-6s>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $75
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $45

</div>
<div id=iphone-6+>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $75
<br>CHARGE PORT: $48
<br>HOME BUTTON: $48
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $45

</div>
<div id=iphone-6>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $70
<br>CHARGE PORT: $40
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>
<div id=iphone-5se>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $70
<br>CHARGE PORT: $40
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>
<div id=iphone-5s>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $55
<br>CHARGE PORT: $35
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $40
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>
<div id=iphone-5c>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $55
<br>CHARGE PORT: $35
<br>HOME BUTTON: $35
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $40
<br>CAMERA: $35

</div>
<div id=iphone-5>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $55
<br>CHARGE PORT: $40
<br>HOME BUTTON: $35
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $40
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("brand").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("model").value
    var a = document.getElementById("model1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("model2").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("apple");
    var e = document.getElementById("samsung");
    var f = document.getElementById("lg");
    var aa = document.getElementById("iphone-xs-max");
    var ab = document.getElementById("iphone-xs");
    var ac = document.getElementById("iphone-x");
    var ad = document.getElementById("iphone-8+");
    var ae = document.getElementById("iphone-8");
    var af = document.getElementById("iphone-7+");
    var ag = document.getElementById("iphone-7");
    var ah = document.getElementById("iphone-6s+");
    var ai = document.getElementById("iphone-6s");
    var aj = document.getElementById("iphone-6+");
    var ak = document.getElementById("iphone-6");
    var al = document.getElementById("iphone-5se");
    var am = document.getElementById("iphone-5s");
    var an = document.getElementById("iphone-5c");
    var ao = document.getElementById("iphone-5");
    aa.style.display = "none";
    ab.style.display = "none";
    ac.style.display = "none";
    ad.style.display = "none";
    ae.style.display = "none";
    af.style.display = "none";
    ag.style.display = "none";
    ah.style.display = "none";
    ai.style.display = "none";
    aj.style.display = "none";
    ak.style.display = "none";
    al.style.display = "none";
    am.style.display = "none";
    an.style.display = "none";
    ao.style.display = "none";
    d.style.display = "none";
    e.style.display = "none";
    f.style.display = "none";
    if (x==1) {
    d.style.display = "block";
        if (a==1) {
        aa.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone Xs Max";
                }
        if (a==2) {
        ab.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone Xs";
                }
        if (a==3) {
        ac.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone X";
                }
        if (a==4) {
        ad.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 8+";
                }
        if (a==5) {
        ae.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 8";
                } 
        if (a==6) {
        af.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 7+";
                }
        if (a==7) {
        ag.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 7";
                }
        if (a==8) {
        ah.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 6s+"
        ;
                }
        if (a==9) {
        ai.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 6s";
                }
        if (a==10) {
        aj.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "iPhone 6+";
                }
        if (a==11) {
        ak.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 6";
                }
        if (a==12) {
        al.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5SE";
                }
        if (a==13) {
        am.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5s";
                }
        if (a==14) {
        an.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5C";
                }
        if (a==15) {
        ao.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5";
                }
        if (a==16) {
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
                }                
    }
    if (x==2) {
    e.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
    }
    if (x==3) {
    f.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
    }
    if (x==4) {
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I add CSS the whole thing breaks.

**Dropdown with CSS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
p.sansserif {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: Red;
}
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: Red;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
</style>
</head>     

<body onload="myFunction()" text="white">

<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="brand" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">Select Brand
  <option value="1">Apple
  <option value="2">Samsung
  <option value="3">LG
  <option value="4">Other
</select>
</div>
<div id="apple" class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
 <select id="model1" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">Select Model
  <option value="1">iPhone Xs Max
  <option value="2">iPhone Xs
  <option value="3">iPhone X
  <option value="4">iPhone 8+
  <option value="5">iPhone 8
  <option value="6">iPhone 7+
  <option value="7">iPhone 7
  <option value="8">iPhone 6s+
  <option value="9">iPhone 6s
  <option value="10">iPhone 6+
  <option value="11">iPhone 6
  <option value="12">iPhone 5SE
  <option value="13">iPhone 5S
  <option value="14">iPhone 5C
  <option value="15">iPhone 5
  <option value="16">Other
</select>
</div>
<div id="samsung" class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="model2" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">Select Model
  <option value="1">Galaxy S9+
  <option value="2">Galaxy S9
  <option value="3">Galaxy S8+
  <option value="4">Galaxy S8
  <option value="5">Galaxy S7 Edge
  <option value="6">Galaxy S7
  <option value="7">Galaxy S6 Edge+
  <option value="8">Galaxy S6 Edge
  <option value="9">Galaxy S6
  <option value="10">Note 9
  <option value="11">Note 8
  <option value="12">Note 7
  <option value="13">Note 5
  <option value="14">Other
</select>
</div>
<div id="lg" class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
<select id="model" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0">Select Model
  <option value="1">LG G7
  <option value="2">LG G6
  <option value="3">LG G5
  <option value="4">LG Stylo 4+
  <option value="5">LG Stylo 4
  <option value="6">LG Stylo 3
  <option value="7">LG Stylo 2
  <option value="8">Other
</select>

</div>
<p class="sansserif" id="product"></p>

<div id=iphone-xs-max>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-xs>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-x>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-8+>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-8>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-7+>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $110
<br>CHARGE PORT: $60
<br>SPEAKER: $45
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $55
<br>REAR CAMERA: $115

</div>
<div id=iphone-7>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $105
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>REAR CAMERA: $55

</div>

<div id=iphone-6s+>
<p class="sansserif">
SCREEN: $80
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $50
<br>SPEAKER: $40
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>FRONT CAMERA: $40
<br>REAR CAMERA: $70

</div>
<div id=iphone-6s>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $75
<br>CHARGE PORT: $45
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $45

</div>
<div id=iphone-6+>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $75
<br>CHARGE PORT: $48
<br>HOME BUTTON: $48
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $45

</div>
<div id=iphone-6>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $70
<br>CHARGE PORT: $40
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>
<div id=iphone-5se>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $70
<br>CHARGE PORT: $40
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $45
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>
<div id=iphone-5s>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $55
<br>CHARGE PORT: $35
<br>HOME BUTTON: $40
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $40
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>
<div id=iphone-5c>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $55
<br>CHARGE PORT: $35
<br>HOME BUTTON: $35
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $40
<br>CAMERA: $35

</div>
<div id=iphone-5>
<p class="sansserif">
<br>SCREEN: $55
<br>CHARGE PORT: $40
<br>HOME BUTTON: $35
<br>SPEAKER: $35
<br>BATTERY: $40
<br>CAMERA: $40

</div>

<script>
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("brand").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("model").value
    var a = document.getElementById("model1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("model2").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("apple");
    var e = document.getElementById("samsung");
    var f = document.getElementById("lg");
    var aa = document.getElementById("iphone-xs-max");
    var ab = document.getElementById("iphone-xs");
    var ac = document.getElementById("iphone-x");
    var ad = document.getElementById("iphone-8+");
    var ae = document.getElementById("iphone-8");
    var af = document.getElementById("iphone-7+");
    var ag = document.getElementById("iphone-7");
    var ah = document.getElementById("iphone-6s+");
    var ai = document.getElementById("iphone-6s");
    var aj = document.getElementById("iphone-6+");
    var ak = document.getElementById("iphone-6");
    var al = document.getElementById("iphone-5se");
    var am = document.getElementById("iphone-5s");
    var an = document.getElementById("iphone-5c");
    var ao = document.getElementById("iphone-5");
    aa.style.display = "none";
    ab.style.display = "none";
    ac.style.display = "none";
    ad.style.display = "none";
    ae.style.display = "none";
    af.style.display = "none";
    ag.style.display = "none";
    ah.style.display = "none";
    ai.style.display = "none";
    aj.style.display = "none";
    ak.style.display = "none";
    al.style.display = "none";
    am.style.display = "none";
    an.style.display = "none";
    ao.style.display = "none";
    d.style.display = "none";
    e.style.display = "none";
    f.style.display = "none";
    if (x==1) {
    d.style.display = "block";
        if (a==1) {
        aa.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone Xs Max";
                }
        if (a==2) {
        ab.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone Xs";
                }
        if (a==3) {
        ac.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone X";
                }
        if (a==4) {
        ad.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 8+";
                }
        if (a==5) {
        ae.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 8";
                } 
        if (a==6) {
        af.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 7+";
                }
        if (a==7) {
        ag.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 7";
                }
        if (a==8) {
        ah.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 6s+"
        ;
                }
        if (a==9) {
        ai.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 6s";
                }
        if (a==10) {
        aj.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "iPhone 6+";
                }
        if (a==11) {
        ak.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 6";
                }
        if (a==12) {
        al.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5SE";
                }
        if (a==13) {
        am.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5s";
                }
        if (a==14) {
        an.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5C";
                }
        if (a==15) {
        ao.style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "iPhone 5";
                }
        if (a==16) {
        document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
                }                
    }
    if (x==2) {
    e.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
    }
    if (x==3) {
    f.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
    }
    if (x==4) {
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = "Please Contact Us!!";
    }

}
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

It's been a while since i've done this stuff and it's a bit fuzzy to me and i can't figure out what could be wrong. Unfortunately it all needs to be in one string as it is going into a HTML module and is not able to pull from other files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you make Code snippet and explain a bit more about your problem .

Comment: The code of "Dropdown with CSS" works fine for me with no error. what is the problem?